# Mutex and signal() and wait() operations

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore

I have two question about mutexes:
1. When a mutex variable equals to 1, and we do a signal() operation on it, what is expected to happen?
2. When mutex equals to 0, and we do a wait(), then the thread is blocked, and mutex stays 0. correct? After a while, another thread makes a signal() operation, then the blocking is released. What will be the value of the mutex now? 0 or 1?

Comment: Why don't you read your textbook or do a google search?

Comment: What is 'signal' on the mutex? Also, mutexes are **not** 0 or 1, they are locked or unlocked.

Comment: Pthread mutexes don't have 1 or 0 values, but can be locked or unlocked. Read a good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). It looks like you are confused!

Comment: I think he might be talking about semaphores? https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/SEMA/basics.html

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is not mutex essentially a binary semaphore?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, of course not. Mutex is a mutex, semaphore is a semaphore. They have a very imporant and distinct properties.

Comment: @SergeyA You may like to edit Wikipedia then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semaphores_vs._mutexes

Comment: OK. so maybe I was confused. I thought that mutex is a binary semaphore and 1=unlocked and 0=locked. 

I read many times that a mutex is a binary semaphore. Isn't it?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, Max, you should know by now that Wikip is not the authority on programming topics. Although it lists enough properties already to clearly show that mutexes are not sempahores, there is one which it fails to list. The deal changer.

Comment: @CrazySynthax, no, it is not. Never was, never will be. Internet is full of false statements.

Comment: @CrazySynthax Mutex is conceptually a binary semaphore and a binary semaphore can be used instead of a mutex. Your thinking was correct.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, please avoid making false statements. If you do not know something, ask.

Comment: OK. so I'll rephrase:
1. When a semaphore equals to its initial value , and we do a signal() operation on it, what is expected to happen?
2. When a semaphore equals to 0, and we do a wait(), then the thread is blocked, and semaphore stays 0. correct? After a while, another thread makes a signal() operation, then the blocking is released. What will be the value of the semaphore now? 0 or 1?

Comment: @SergeyA I suggest you practice what you preach.

Comment: @SergeyA So what is the conceptual difference between mutex and binary semaphore? To be honest I agree with Maxim.

Comment: Will post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So conceptually mutex has 2 states: locked and unlocked. If it is represented by 0 or 1 is not important here.

If you unlock (i.e. signal) a mutex it changes its state from locked to unlocked. Further unlocking doesn't change its state and it actually doesn't do anything.

If a mutex is unlocked and you call wait then the call does nothing (it does not wait) and the thread continues its execution.

When a mutex is locked and you call wait then the thread is blocked. When other thread calls unlock then blocking is released and the mutex becomes unlocked.

The most important thing is that unlock and lock operations are atomic in the sense that parallel calls cannot overlap each other to produce corrupted result (formally: parallel calls to lock/unlock are always equivalent to some serialized call history). Otherwise the whole concept of mutex would be simply stupid. :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading the comments (and original unedited question) it is clear that there is enough people out there who believe binary sempahores to be interchangeable with mutexes. If we speak in practical terms (that is, `pthread mutex` and System V `semaphore`) they are very different. I will try to outline the most important differences below.

1. Conceptual ownership. Mutexes are owned by their locker, sempahores are not owned by anybody. This leads to two disticntions. **Very important** one is that mutexes can (should) only be unlocked by the owner (locker thread), while sempahores can be unlocked by any thread (see below for permissions). The less important thing is that mutexes can be made re-entrant - that is, can be locked multiple times with the owner thread - while semaphores can't behave so. I say it is less important because reentrant mutexes almost always present design flaw.
2. Semaphores are objects which are more or less indepenent of the user. They can be created, used and destroyed by completely unrelated processess or threads, which do not even have to know anything of each other (or execute at the same time). For example, a process might create a semaphore and than die, and other processes can use it, while third process will remove it). Semaphores have *permissions* associated with them (not unlike file permissions), while mutexes have no such thing - anybody who have access to mutex technically can do anything with it.
3. Semaphores are process-shared. That is, they can be used by multiple processes without extra efforts. Default mutexes are single-process only, if the same mutex is to be used by multiple processes, it has to be created in a special mode.

Comment: I don't understand something. 
You write: "mutexes can (should) only be unlocked by the owner (locker thread)"
On the other hand, you write: "anybody who have access to mutex technically can do anything with it."

How does it make sense?

Comment: These are not differences between mutex and semaphore. These are differences in how they are used. But I have no problem in imagining mutex without owner or shared between processes. What you are talking about is these concrete implementations (`pthread` vs `System V`), not about concepts.

Comment: @CrazySynthax, well, consider following: "Someone told me, that in soccer I can not run and hold the ball. I just tried it yesterday, and nothing happened!" mutex specification says, that it should only be unlocked by owner thread. Yet you can call pthread_mutex_unlock() on the mutex which you didn't lock - and it will be unlocked (at least, an attempt would be made). Sempahores have permissions enforced by the OS. An attempt to unlock a semaphore without needed permissions will trigger an error.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkinm, it does not and doesn't claim so. It addresses your (and other peoples) misunderstandings.

Comment: @freakish, I see no reason to talk about concepts, as everybody has a different idea of concept in their mind. Specific implementations, on the other hand, are documented and, what is more important, are really used.

Comment: Sounds like you are having difficulty grasping the concept of a concept.

Comment: @SergeyA IMHO absolutely not: mutex and semaphore are well defined in literature. They don't depend on "different ideas". And it is actually more important to talk about concepts then specific implementations since implementations can change while mathematical concepts rarely (if ever) change. Not to mention that concepts are not OS dependent. Do you think Windows does not have mutexes? I have no idea how they work under Windows (in terms of privileges, etc.) but I do know what they are supposed to do. Because I know the concept.

Comment: @freakish, I have no idea what are your interests, but my interests are to write well-behaved production-quality code. If I am to write such a code armed with 'concept' knowledge of mutex, without knowing what specific mutex implementation does (pthread_mutex, for instance), and than start unlocking mutex from non-owning thread, my program will exhibit hard-to-catch, mind-boggling, user-killing bug. I can't afford this. If your interest lies in academia, than of course, real world is of no interest to you.

Comment: @SergeyA Actually if you know a concept you can reuse your knowledge which improves your work performance. Otherwise you would have to learn implementation details of every single thing you'll ever encounter. What a waste of time and brain capacity. Anyway I understand your point of view and I respect it. We can only agree to disagree. :)